# Why does NuGet put packages at the "solution level"?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

When you add a nuget package to a project it puts the assemblies in a /packages folder at the solution level.

I know that there are ways to change this, but I'm wondering why this is the default location, as it seems very unhelpful for these reasons:

1) If you have a project that is part of multiple solutions, the /packages folder won't necessarily be where you the project expects it.

2) You are expected to manually check it into source control for other team members, which is much less convenient than if it was part of the project that needs it.

3) If you move the project somewhere else on the file system or to a different machine that doesn't have the full code base, it won't find the /packages folder where it expects to.

It seems all of these would be resolved if NuGet just used a /packages folder inside the project, not the solution. And that seems like a much more logical place to put packages that the project relies on anyway.

So... I'm assuming that there were/are some good reasons for doing it at the solution level, and I'm hoping someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 4):

You should have a read at this, that explains how to use nuget without commiting packages to your source control, and by side effect solve points 1 and 3 of your question : http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/03/using-nuget-without-committing-packages.html

Comment: Hmmmm, that might help.  Will nuget automatically download the old versions of packages?  i.e. If I grab some source from version control that includes v1.1 of some nuget provided assembly, and the current version of that assembly is 3.4, what will happen?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's to save disk space. If you had a large solution with 50 projects and you used a package in every one of those, you would end up with 50 copies of that package, binaries and all. Whereas keeping them at solution level is far more efficient in that respect.

In terms of source control, you shouldn't be putting your actual packages folder in there. Just add the packages.config file and either do what David Ebbo suggests in the blog post mentioned by [mathieu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971/mathieu) or create a simple batch file to download all your packages based on the packages.config files it can find.

It's not much effort to create your own company nuget feed, so you can keep your private packages in there.

Comment: Does creating oru own nuget feed help with this problem?  It sounded like from that blog post that people who used both private and public nuget feeds were unable to make use of the technique described.  My other concern is that I feel we need these assemblies in source control *somewhere*, b/c if we need to perform maintenance on some 4 year old code we need to have the version of the assemblies that were deployed with the project.  So if they have to go in source control anyway, why not include them in your project?

Comment: If you cannot reproduce the assemblies from code then, IMO, you need to think about whether that will cause you a problem. It does for the company I work for, so we've put automated building, packaging and publishing in place, along with using semver, that allows us to recreate any version of any assembly and also to move the common stuff forwards without fear of breaking everything that depends on it. I apologise if that last part of my answer caused offense, none was intended, I was merely pointing out that it's not a difficult thing to set up should you feel you need it.

Comment: If it is to save disk space, it's incredibly short sighted. COM and dll hell anyone?

Comment: I must be missing something here. COM dll hell was/is a problem with only being able to have one version of a dll on a system. I still have to deal with a website which uses COM, so I know only too well (I die a little inside each time I go near it!!). NuGet stores different versions of packages (and hence dlls) in separate folders.